# Mobile Sitemap - Error 404 - WMT dont index it?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, googlebot-mobile

I have a site that is not responsive. It has 3 versions : PC, tablet and mobile, every version has different pages .

I have made 2 sitemaps: one for the PC version and one for the mobile version.

The URL of the mobile and the PC site looks like this: `xxx@example.com...` The difference is that they don't have the same pages.

I saved in the FTP server the mobile sitemap as this example: `sitemap-mobile.xml` but when I submit it to webmaster tools it shows me `404` error.

Do I have to make 3 different sitemaps for every version of the site? And if so , what can be the correct forms to do that ?

Comment: You have mobile site that is not responsive?